# Haskell - Chess - which next moves are possible?

Tags: haskell, chess

I want to write a function that takes a chess figure with a position and tell me which moves this figure can make with his next move.

For the king I was able to do this.

```
type Position = (Int,Int)

data Piece = Piece {
    _position :: Position,
    _color :: String}

nextMoves :: Piece -> [Position]
nextMoves king = filter (onTheBoard) (filter (/= (xOld,yOld)) 
                        [(x,y) | x <- [(xOld-1)..(xOld+1)], y <- [(yOld-1)..(yOld+1)]])
    where
        xOld = fst(_position king)
        yOld = snd(_position king)
```

He stands on (1,3) and my function gives me [(1,2),(1,4),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4)].

Now I want to do the same for a bishop or a knight. But how can I use filter for this issue? 
Thanks for a tipp.

//edit: I've changed my check to a help function:

```
onTheBoard :: Position -> Bool
onTheBoard (x,y) = elem x [1..8] && elem y [1..8]
```

Comment: I think it should be >= (1,1) and <= (8,8)

Comment: Still it won't work. Try at position (7,8) it will give you (7,9)  which is not a valid position.

Comment: That's true. Damn it. But i have no other clever idea to compare them.. maybe with a help function.
onTheBoard :: Position -> Bool
onTheBoard (x,y) = elem x [1..8] && elem y [1..8]
Works fine^^

Comment: King can actually move two spots if it's castling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no way to tell which piece (king, bishop, knight, etc.) a `Piece` is. `nextMoves king` matches all pieces, regardless of which type it is. To figure out the moves for other pieces, you'll need to be able to discriminate between them. You'll need something like

```
data PieceType = Pawn | Knight | Bishop | Rook | Queen | King

data Piece = Piece {
    _position :: Position,
    _color :: String,
    _pieceType :: PieceType}
```

Then you can write more cases for `nextMoves`

```
nextMoves :: Piece -> [Position]
nextMoves piece =
    case _pieceType piece of
        King   -> filter (<= (1,1)) (filter (>= (8,8)) (filter (/= (xOld,yOld)) 
                        [(x,y) | x <- [(xOld-1)..(xOld+1)], y <- [(yOld-1)..yOld+1)]]))(yOld+1)]]))
        Queen  -> ...
        Rook   -> ...
        Bishop -> ...
        Knight -> ...
        Pawn   -> ...
    where
        xOld = fst(_position piece)
        yOld = snd(_position piece)
```

You could extract the filtering that the move must be on the board from the rest of the rules.

If you are aiming for the actual game of chess, there are other rules for whether a move is valid that depend on the rest of the state of the board.

#### Filtering

You also have a problem with the filtering, as pointed out by Priyatham. The `Ord` instance for typles `(,)` first compares the first element of the tuple, then compares the second one. That means, for instance, that `(1, 9) < (2, 0)`. This is called a lexographic ordering, like how entries are alphabetized: first by their first letter, then by their second, etc...

You need to check that each component is individually in the range, which is easily done with `Data.Ix`'s `inRange` and the `fst` and `snd` functions, for example:

```
filter (inRange (1,8) . fst) . filter (inRange (1,8) . snd) . filter (/= (8,8)) $ [(7,9), 9,7), (7,7), (8, 8)]
```

The `Ix` instance for tuples `(,)` checks that both components are `inRange`, so this is equivalent to

```
filter (inRange ((1,1), (8,8))) . filter (/= (8,8)) $ [(7,9), (9,7), (7,7), (8, 8)]
```

Comment: A few very good points there. I thought that I need sth like "instance of" in java here. Because with my code there are overlapping the pattern. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: There's even one move that's only legal based on board history, rather than current board position. That one mucks everything up. (Not a large amount, but you need to carry some extra information around.)

Comment: Yes, for En Passant you need to know the most recent opponent's move if it was a pawn taking a double-step move.

Comment: And you still have to consider castling, which blows up the model of moving "a piece" entirely.